# Nginx - rewrite images address

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I need a rewrite rule for Nginx which will rewrite all images on:

```
http://mysite.com/index.php/article/foo/images/image.(png|jpg|gif)
```

to address:

```
http://mysite.com/images/image.(png|jpg|gif)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want something like:

```
 rewrite ^/index.php/article/foo/images/(.*).(png|jpg|gif) /images/$1.$2 ;
```

Comment: Heh, any chance you can accept or +1 the answer in the next 30 minutes? I'm trying to hit 200 points in a day!